# SELECT COUNT(id) AS GROUP BY MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I have a table of items that have been moved to a different store. I am retrieving all `moved_items` in addition to calculating `is_sold` to determine if they have been sold.

I also need to calculate `total_moves` for each item as it may have been moved multiple times.

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
SELECT
  sold_items.id IS NOT NULL AS is_sold ,
  COUNT(moved_items.id) AS total_moved GROUP BY serial_number -- This is the part I need help with
FROM all_items
INNER JOIN moved_items ON all_items.serial_number= moved_items.serial_number
LEFT JOIN sold_items ON all_items.serial_number= sold_items.serial_number
```

Is there a quick, efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You have all the right pieces, but all in the wrong places:

```
SELECT
  serial_number ,
  SUM(CASE WHEN sold_items.id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS is_sold ,
  COUNT(moved_items.id) AS total_moved 
FROM all_items
    INNER JOIN moved_items ON all_items.serial_number= moved_items.serial_number
    LEFT JOIN sold_items ON all_items.serial_number= sold_items.serial_number
GROUP BY serial_number
```

You'll need a CASE to do that condition up in the SELECT portion of your query to see if sold_items.id is not null (Assuming you are wanting a count here since you didn't specify... the sum(case...) will take care of that with the condition). You may also find that a simple `count(sold_items.id)` may suffice here since, I believe, NULLs won't be included in the count.

GROUP BY's go at the end of the SQL Statement. I'm also assuming you want your serial_number in the result set since you are grouping on it.